# Android Unit testing - Have a test wait on a response

Tags: android, multithreading, unit-testing

So I've got an Android library that I need to do unit testing on. You pass the library some handlers, and I need to unit test based on the messages sent to those handlers from the library.

The problem is, I don't know how to tell a test to wait until I get a response back. I have a timer checking the response every 10 seconds in my test method and if it sees a response is does an assert, but the test method schedules the timer task and then finishes as successful instead of waiting for an assert in the timer task.

Is there a way to have the test explicitly wait until it runs into an assert before finishing? Or some other way of accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create mocks of the handlers. Mocks can/should replace the actual handlers in the unit test of the library. You have full control over mocks, and avoid threading issues (unit testing is damn hard with threading involved).